# In my iOS app, how can I show a list of missed local notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilocalnotification

I want to ensure that all notifications which reach my app should be attended by user.

I would explain in more detail.

Suppose my app which receives local notifications is in back ground and my screen is OFF. And my app gets more than one ( say 3 ) local notification during that time. if I ON my device screen, in locked screen , I will see 3 notification. but user can select only one. If user choose one of these, user will never get a chance to see other two notifications. I want to show a list of those unread notifications in my app view.

How can I do this? Please help